# Divs not showing correctly, plus resize issue

Tags: css, html, resize

I want three div's next to eachother (I placed them in a .wrapper div so I could float them to the left). The three div's should be centered on the page. So I thought, if I center the .wrapper with margin-left/right: auto, all the three divs would center up. This didnt work.
Also, when I resize the browser the divs move. I don't want that to happen.

I've googled endlessy and put lots of solutions in the script, nothing worked.

Also, it shows differently per browser (firefox, safari and Chrome).

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="lost"><img src="images/lost.png"></div>
        <div id="compass"><img src="images/compass.png"></div>
        <div id="sailor"><img src="images/sailor.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="sea">
        <img src="images/seaAnimated.png" class="sea" id="animatedSea">
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
body,html
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#container
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.wrapper
{
    left:auto;
    right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:8%;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-left:auto;
    padding-right:auto;
    width:100%;
    height:75%;
}

#lost
{
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    clear:both;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#compass
{
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height:75%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#sailor
{
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height:75%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#sea
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:2;
    background-image:url(images/sea.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:bottom;
    height:25%;
    width:100%;
}

#animatedSea
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    width:auto;
    height:25%;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: You've set `.wrapper { width: 100% }`. As such, it'll be the entire width of the browser and the `margin-{left,right}: auto` will do nothing.

Comment: I removed the width, same result.

Comment: Right. You can't center something if there's no space in which to center it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**css**

```
.wrapper{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:8%;
    width:100%;
    height:75%;
}

#lost{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#0C0;
}
#compass{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#06F;
}
#sailor{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#96F;  
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="lost">123</div>
    <div id="compass">456</div>
    <div id="sailor">789</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/AGjDm/)

Comment: That did not work either, the images simply overlapped to the right.

Comment: please check the working code, I have updated it with images  http://jsfiddle.net/AGjDm/1/   its working fine here.

Comment: Thanks! Now the images/divs are centered. However, when I still move the browser they go below eachother. How to avoid that?

Comment: for this you have to give a width in % to the div and make the images max-width: 100%; height: auto;.... here is the updated code. . . http://jsfiddle.net/AGjDm/7/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fixed width on your wrapper to get it to center. You do have to specify a width (and not leave it empty) because divs are block-level, meaning that they fill the entire width by default.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/CBMaX/2

```
.wrapper {
    width: 240px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper
{
 text-align: center;
}
#compass
{
width:33.3%; 
}
#sailor
{
width:33.3%;
}
#lost
{
 width:33.3%;
}
```

Try this css. Include this css into your css.